# xsd validation is failing

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

My xml validation is failing with the following reason:

> Failed to execute goal se.ericsson.jcat.ebs:xml-validation-plugin:1.0.2:validate (default) on project ebs-extensions: Unable to execute mojo: While parsing /home/xchoshu/latestWorkspace/ebs-extensions/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml, at file:/home/xchoshu/latestWorkspace/ebs-extensions/src/main/resources/log4j.xsd, line 18, column 64: src-resolve.4.1: Error resolving component 'ConfigurationType'. It was detected that 'ConfigurationType' has no namespace, but components with no target namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:/home/xchoshu/latestWorkspace/ebs-extensions/src/main/resources/log4j.xsd'. If 'ConfigurationType' is intended to have a namespace, perhaps a prefix needs to be provided. If it is intended that 'ConfigurationType' has no namespace, then an 'import' without a "namespace" attribute should be added to 'file:/home/xchoshu/latestWorkspace/ebs-extensions/src/main/resources/log4j.xsd'. -> [Help 1]

my xds looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Configuration" type="ConfigurationType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="ConfigurationType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:element name="CustomLevels" type="CustomLevelsType"/>
                <xs:element name="CustomLevel" type="CustomLevelType"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="Properties" type="PropertiesType"/>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:element name="Filters" type="FiltersType"/>
                <xs:element name="Filter" type="FilterType"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="ThresholdFilter" type="ThresholdFilterType"/>
            <xs:element name="Appenders" type="AppendersType"/>
            <xs:element name="Loggers" type="LoggersType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="packages" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="status" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="strict" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="advertiser" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="schema" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="PropertiesType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Property" type="PropertyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="AppenderType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Layout" type="LayoutType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:element name="Filters" type="FiltersType"/>
                <xs:element name="Filter" type="FilterType"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="fileName" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="RootType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="AppenderRef" type="AppenderRefType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="level" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="PropertyType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="KeyValuePairType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="AppendersType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Appender" type="AppenderType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="AppenderRefType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="ref" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="LoggerType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:element name="Filters" type="FiltersType"/>
                <xs:element name="Filter" type="FilterType"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="AppenderRef" type="AppenderRefType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="level" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="additivity" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="FilterType" mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="KeyValuePair" type="KeyValuePairType" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="level" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="marker" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="onMatch" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="onMismatch" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="FiltersType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Filter" type="FilterType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="CustomLevelType">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="intLevel" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="CustomLevelsType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="CustomLevel" type="CustomLevelType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="LoggersType" mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Logger" type="LoggerType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="Root" type="RootType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="LayoutType" mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Pattern" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="pattern" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ThresholdFilterType">
        <xs:attribute name="level" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="onMatch" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="onMismatch" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

my xml looks like:

```
 <Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config https://ei-switching.rnd.ki.sw.ericsson.se/browser/jcat-bsp/log4j.xsd">

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="JCATDefaultConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT"
            follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{default} %m [%t] %l%n%ex{full}" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="JCATDefaultConsoleAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
```

can anyone help me in correcting the xsd.
TIA

Regards,
Shubhankar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XSD is missing the namespace declaration *xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config"*. That makes the XSD valid.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config" 
           targetNamespace="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Configuration" type="ConfigurationType"/>
```

But then your XML files has lots of issues

[image]

You are missing the mandatory elements **Properties** and **ThresholdFilters** and **Appenders** should contain at least 1 **Appender** (not a **Console**)

A Sample document would look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid XML 2017 Liquid Studio - Data Designer Edition 15.0.0.6978 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<ns:Configuration xmlns:ns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config C:\Temp\StackOverflow\41177776\Schema.xsd" packages="string" status="string" strict="string" name="string" advertiser="string" schema="string">
    <ns:CustomLevels><!--optional-->
        <ns:CustomLevel name="string" intLevel="string" />
        <ns:CustomLevel name="string" intLevel="string" />
        <ns:CustomLevel name="string" intLevel="string" />
    </ns:CustomLevels>
    <ns:Properties>
        <ns:Property>string</ns:Property>
        <ns:Property>string</ns:Property>
    </ns:Properties>
    <ns:Filters><!--optional-->
        <ns:Filter type="string" level="string" marker="string" onMatch="string" onMismatch="string">
            <ns:KeyValuePair key="string" value="string">string</ns:KeyValuePair>
        </ns:Filter>
    </ns:Filters>
    <ns:ThresholdFilter level="string" onMatch="string" onMismatch="string" />
    <ns:Appenders>
        <ns:Appender type="string" name="string" fileName="string" />
        <ns:Appender type="string" name="string" />
    </ns:Appenders>
    <ns:Loggers>
        <ns:Logger name="string" level="string" additivity="string">
            <ns:AppenderRef ref="string">string</ns:AppenderRef>
        </ns:Logger>
        <ns:Root>
            <ns:AppenderRef ref="string">string</ns:AppenderRef>
        </ns:Root>
    </ns:Loggers>
</ns:Configuration>
```

Comment: i am new to xsd and xml can you help me in arranging them in a proper order.