# Xml file correspond to xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, log4j, xml-validation

I am new to xml validation can anyone help me in creating xml file on the given line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config log4j.xsd">

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="JCATDefaultConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT"
            follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{default} %m [%t] %l%n%ex{full}" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="JCATDefaultConsoleAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

My xsd looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config">
    <xs:element name="Configuration" type="ConfigurationType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="ConfigurationType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:element name="CustomLevels" type="CustomLevelsType"/>
                <xs:element name="CustomLevel" type="CustomLevelType"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="Properties" type="PropertiesType"/>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:element name="Filters" type="FiltersType"/>
                <xs:element name="Filter" type="FilterType"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="ThresholdFilter" type="ThresholdFilterType"/>
            <xs:element name="Appenders" type="AppendersType"/>
            <xs:element name="Loggers" type="LoggersType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="packages" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="status" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="strict" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="advertiser" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="schema" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="PropertiesType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Property" type="PropertyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="AppenderType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Layout" type="LayoutType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:element name="Filters" type="FiltersType"/>
                <xs:element name="Filter" type="FilterType"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="fileName" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="RootType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="AppenderRef" type="AppenderRefType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="level" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="PropertyType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="KeyValuePairType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="AppendersType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Appender" type="AppenderType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="AppenderRefType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="ref" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="LoggerType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:element name="Filters" type="FiltersType"/>
                <xs:element name="Filter" type="FilterType"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="AppenderRef" type="AppenderRefType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="level" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="additivity" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="FilterType" mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="KeyValuePair" type="KeyValuePairType" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="level" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="marker" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="onMatch" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="onMismatch" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="FiltersType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Filter" type="FilterType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="CustomLevelType">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="intLevel" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="CustomLevelsType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="CustomLevel" type="CustomLevelType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="LoggersType" mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Logger" type="LoggerType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="Root" type="RootType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="LayoutType" mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Pattern" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="pattern" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ThresholdFilterType">
        <xs:attribute name="level" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="onMatch" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="onMismatch" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Error i am getting is :

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal se.ericsson.jcat.ebs:xml-validation-plugin:1.0.2:validate (default) on project ebs-extensions: Unable to execute mojo: While parsing /home/xchoshu/latestWorkspace/ebs-extensions/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml, at file:/home/xchoshu/latestWorkspace/ebs-extensions/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml, line 6,  column 16: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Appenders'. One of '{"http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config":CustomLevels, "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config":Properties}' is expected. -> [Help 1]

I would appreciate if someone modifies my xml so that it passes xml validation.

TIA

Comment: Already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177776/xsd-validation-is-failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the schema you provided, by reading the `<xs:complexType name="ConfigurationType">` definition, the `<Configuration>` tag needs to show as children tags (in this order):

1. (*optional*) a `CustomLevels` or `CustomLevel` tag;
2. (**mandatory**) a `Properties` tag;
3. (*optional*)  a `Filter` or a `Filters` tag;
4. (**mandatory**) a `ThresholdFilter` tag;
5. (**mandatory**) an `Appenders` tag;
6. (**mandatory**) a `Loggers` tag.